# Which font is used for Oakley's "A Story of Disruption" video?

Tags: font-identification, serif

What might this typeface be? It's used throughout [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozwtG8Q0idc). I'm primarily looking at the 'A', 'V', and 'W'. Any similar fonts would be great.

[image: Typeface]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! It's always beneficial to include the source of where you found the source image. I was able to use a reverse image search to find it and edit it in for you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say Decima Light:
http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tipografiaramis/decima/light/

I just used the font search:
http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/